# не работают события Telethon

Tags: asyncio, telethon, action

```
import pymysql, time, asyncio, requests, sys, threading, os, socks
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest

pid = os.getpid()
print(pid)

r = requests.post('http://ip:5000/api/select/account', json={"token": ""})
if r.json()['Status'] == 2:
    print("Нет доступных аккаунтов")
    sys.exit()
else:
    x, Phone, Api_id, Api_hash = r.json()['Id'], r.json()['Phone'], r.json()['Api_id'], r.json()['Api_hash']

client = TelegramClient(session=str(f'C:\\Users\\Админ\\Desktop\\RG\\new\\session{x}'), api_id=Api_id, api_hash=Api_hash).start()

a = requests.post('http://ip:5000/api/set/status/pid', json={"token": "", "x": x, "pid": pid})

@client.on(events.NewMessage(func=lambda e: e.is_private))
async def handler(event):
    try:
        print(event.message.message)#текст
        await client.get_dialogs()
        id = event.message.peer_id.user_id#юзерка пользователя
        info = await client.get_entity(event.message.peer_id.user_id)
        print(info.to_dict()['username'])#юзерка
        username = info.to_dict()['username']
        if username is None:
            username = "None"
        z = requests.post('http://ip:5000/api/upload/message', json={"token": "", "x": x, "Text": event.message.message, "User_id": id, "Username": username, "Number": Phone, "id": x})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

async def join(Task, client):
    print("1")
    print(Task)
    return await client(JoinChannelRequest(Task))

async def send(Task, Message, client):
    print("2")
    print(Task, Message)
    return await client.send_message(f"{Task}", f"{Message}")

#/api/check/task/account
def t():
    while True:
        r = requests.post('http://ip:5000/api/check/task/account', json={"token": "", "Phone": Phone})
        if r.json()['status'] == 2:
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            Type = r.json()['Type']
            if Type == "join":
                Task = r.json()['Task']
                _thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(join(Task, client),)).start()
            if Type == "send":
                Task = r.json()['Task']
                Message = r.json()['Message']
                _thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(send(Task, Message, client),)).start()

threading.Thread(target=t, args=()).start()

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

> При отправке задания на функции (join, send) просто не выполняются,
> хотя если запускать не в асинхронке все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asyncio.run запускает новый эвент луп. Да и не стоит мешать асинхронщину с тредами. Переделай тред [на таск](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/asyncio.html#client-run-until-disconnected-blocks):

```
async def t():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    while True:
        r = await loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            lambda: requests.post(
                'http://ip:5000/api/check/task/account',
                json={"token": "", "Phone": Phone}
            )
        )
        rjson = await loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            r.json
        )
        if rjson['status'] == 2:
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        else:
            Type = rjson['Type']
            if Type == "join":
                Task = rjson['Task']
                await join(Task, client)
            if Type == "send":
                Task = rjson['Task']
                Message = rjson['Message']
                await send(Task, Message, client)

client.loop.create_task(t())
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot_starter.py", line 73, in <module>
    asyncio.create_task(t())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 381, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 't' was never awaited

Comment: поправил, но там ещё могут быть вопросы)

Comment: `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(t())`


переделал чутка)

Comment: Твой вариант тоже работает. Вопрос решен

Comment: пока asyncio.get_event_loop() работает как Singleton (один луп и один тред), твой вариант будет работать.)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь